# Simple Javascript Commenting Form

Tags: javascript, webforms, textarea, comments

I have a textarea and a submit button.

When the button is clicked, I want the value of the textarea to be placed in a container (in a paragraph tag). And I want this value to be stored on my web server.

How do I write this?

Thanks

Comment: That might be too broad of a question to ask here. Try an approach and see what happens. That will produce more specific questions which will be better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a starting point for you. The following works 100% but **you have to put a little bit of work into it too**.

html -

```
<div id="MyComments"></div>
<input type="text" id="name"/>
<textarea id="comment"></textarea>
<input type="submit" id="" value="Go!" onclick="comment();"/>
```

Javascript-

```
function comment(){
//Store elements in a variable.
var name= document.getElementById("name");
var comment= document.getElementById("comment");
//I would recommend checking/validating the users input.
var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
//Sending the comment to AddComment.php
var url = "AddComment.php";
var vars = "name="+name.value+"&comment="+comment.value;
    hr.open("POST", url, true);
    hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
    var return_data = hr.responseText;
/*Comment post successfully sent.
return_data = your php reply, you can append a new element to your webpage to 
display the php result/comment.
Remove loading icon if you have added.*/
var target = document.getElementById('MyComments');
var ElementType = document.createElement('p');
//Set attributes to your element /onclick/ID/Class/style(in-line style)
ElementType.setAttribute('align', 'center');
target.appendChild(ElementType);
//Insert the php result into the new P element.
ElementType.innerHTML=return_data;
}}
//Send the comment to the php
hr.send(vars);
//Here you can display a loading icon.
}
```

PHP -

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['name'])&&($_POST['comment'])){
die('<b>'.$_POST['name'].':</b> <i>'.$_POST['comment'].'</i>');
}
?>
```

All you have to do from here is validate the users input in the javascript, validate it server-side in php before saving (Better to be safe than sorry). You will have to think of your own method of saving the comment but me personally i would use MYSQL. 
Hope this is a good starting point for you! 
If this answers your question please mark this post.